# Removing strikethrough unicode text?

Tags: php, regex

I've got input from users once in a while who are using those annoying stikethrough text generators and it's breaking my code.

I've tried some code I found here on SO...

```
$string = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $string);
```

And it works, but I need it to ONLY replace the combining long stroke overlays.

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0336/index.htm

However, adding this to my regex alone doesn't do the trick. It finds nothing.

Help!

Comment: Are you asking to change `̶f̶o̶o̶ ̶b̶a̶r` to `foo bar`?

Comment: Sam, that's dead on.

Comment: `$str = str_replace("\xCC\xB6", "", $str);` would help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this completely works but for what I've tested it removes the strikethroughs.
Thanks @Jonny 5 for mentioning `\xCC\xB6`

```
$text = "s̶t̶r̶i̶k̶e̶t̶h̶r̶o̶u̶g̶h̶";
$st = "\xCC\xB6";/*seems to work best even with other alphabets*/
/*[chr(204), chr(182)];#add others if necessary?*/
var_dump($text);
if(preg_match("#[" . $st . "]#", $text)){/*preg_match("#[" . implode('|', $st) . "]#", $text)*/
    $text = str_replace($st, '', $text);
}
var_dump($text);
```

Comment: Why not just do the `str_replace()` and avoid running the extra `preg_match()` to see if there are any characters needing replaced.

Comment: I put that in so the user can see how he can check for it and replace it and he can decide if its needed.