# Put Text To Default - V̶u̶l̶n̶e̶r̶a̶b̶i̶l̶i̶t̶y̶ -> Vulnerability

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I'm using PHP, getting some text strings from a remote API, and I'd like something in addition to "strip_tags()" and other sanitizing functions that will show the text as it is if it is decorated by a crossline, underline, etc: 
Desired functionality: to turn: | V̶u̶l̶n̶e̶r̶a̶b̶i̶l̶i̶t̶y̶ |   into   | Vulnerability |

CSS won't do the job since the actual chars should be changed, either in the back (in my case PHP) or in the front (Javascript).

[image: CSS wont do the job]

Comment: CSS [text-decoration-line: line-through](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-decoration-line) will do the job.

Comment: Thanks, but:
1. It is not doing the job. The chars themselves have the line-through.
2. I'm looking for a backend solution.

Comment: The *javascript* tag suggests client side. You need to update the question with more information, as it stands it's way too vague. `text-deocration: none !important` may work. Or not.

Comment: Please see the updated question. a PHP solution may be better but if none exists I'll have to use a front solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing strikethrough unicode text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25733101/removing-strikethrough-unicode-text)